# service bus maven error - unknown packaging sbar

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jdeveloper, oracle-service-bus

I am new to maven / pom.xml and am following the below link to create an oracle service bus project and package it into custom packaging type "sbar".

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/osb_maven_project.htm#MAVEN8971

The Project gets generated properly (from the command --> mvn archetype:generate ... ) but when I execute the below command I get an error

```
mvn package -DoracleHome=/path/to/osbhome
```

> [ERROR] Unknown packaging: sbar @ line 16, column 16

project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-servicebus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>my-servicebus-application</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>sbar</packaging>     <!--getting error on this line-->

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-servicebus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>package</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

application pom.xml

```
<project>
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my-servicebus-application</groupId>
<artifactId>my-servicebus-application</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>System</module>
    <module>my-project</module>
</modules>
...
</project>
```

system pom.xml

```
<project>
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>System</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>sbar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus</groupId>
    <artifactId>sbar-system-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
...
</project>
```

I am using JDeveloper 12.1.3.0.0 and Maven 3.0.5.
(I get the same error if I run it either from JDeveloper or from command promt)

Please help me solve this error.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I haven't really sat down to work with any of the Maven POM's for OSB, SOA, etc., but I do know that your maven plugin probably isn't on the default [M2 repository](https://search.maven.org).  It probably can't find your packaging type of `sbar` because it's not included in your repository.  I'm assuming you're using their supplied maven and maven repo following this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN8853

Comment: ok...will run the mvn install and push commands again and check if M2 repo gets updated and it can fetch the details for sbar packaging...Thanks!....& yes I am using the supplied maven as mentioned in your link

Comment: @NickKlauer the error is gone now !! The packaging sbar was not properly synched I guess into the M2 repository. I just deleted my local M2 repository folder and ran the maven install and push commands again and now it is not giving me any error :) Thanks again

Comment: @NickKlauer you can put an answer to this question and I will accept it. As you pointed it out correctly that pom was not able to find it in the M2 repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really sat down to work with any of the Maven POM's for OSB, SOA, etc., but I do know that your maven plugin probably isn't on the default [M2 repository](https://search.maven.org).  It probably can't find your packaging type of `sbar` because it's not included in your repository.  I'm assuming you're using their supplied maven and maven repo following this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN8853